# Feature : Flag for currently online user

Tags: feature-request

**Feature Request**

I am thinking it would be good feature if there is a green flag to indicate currently online user, at-least it would help while using the chat room.

Comment: Also if we tag any user name in comment or in answer and if user don't visit site for 1 or 2 days, it should send an email to users account.

Comment: @BabyinMagento that could become super spammy. There's the discussion chat for this I reckon that's enough. People here are volunteers not online support so I disagree with the email notifications system.

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism you are absolutely right, i completely agree, why i thought this idea is , if one user asked question before 1 or 2 months & if someone posted an answer with how to  find solution ,  using that idea if the user solved the problem, that op should post an answer for that,  so that it will be helpfull for other community members & save their time in future. but once they get idea, they will never visit site again.

Comment: If this were implemented then we would have to send @Marius money for the burn-in on his screen.

Comment: This question is not specific to the Magento StackExchange, but would apply to the entire network and I'm sure it would've been requested before

Answer (score 6):

It has been asked before you can find the details here: [Is there a way to identify whether users are online or not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4445/317574)

Basically, SE is not a social network it's a programming Q&A website, there's no real need for this feature on the website.

Comment: i love the word **SE is not a social network**..:)